# Content Security Policy Safari issue

Tags: security, content-security-policy

I am relatively new to CSPs and was testing out a policy for a server. Everything is going fine with it but on Safari there are images that do not load. These images are visible on other browsers like firefox when the policy is in place but just not Safari. The log produces violations for the "style-src-elem" with a blocked uris that are mostly inline but has a couple uris and status code 0.

I tried to add the specific uris and also tried *.website.com and so on but it still does not show on Safari. The website is perfectly fine on Firefox.

Example violation: "blocked-uri": "inline",
"status-code": 0,
"source-file": "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=730777b85d5b1ca1d340c5a3e49ec603",
"line-number": 53,
"column-number": 2230

CSP Header: Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com data:; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com google-analytics.com *.clarity.ms ; img-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com/a?id=UA-336357-8&cv=1&v=3&t=t&pid=1119290718&rv=b90&es=1&e=gtm.init&eid=0&u=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIA&h=Ag&tc=1&z=0 https://c.bing.com/c.gif?ctsa=mr&CtsSyncId=E9B0604238FA40F8AB17E04C350255D5&RedC=c.clarity.ms&MXFR=2D92222A68936A860A0F30776C9364BD c.clarity.ms *.clarity.ms *.googleusercontent.com [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) *.google.com google.com data: ; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com; style-src-elem 'self' fonts.googleapis.com *.facebook.net [www.gstatic.com](http://www.gstatic.com) ; script-src code.jquery.com *.googlesyndication.com *.facebook.net *.googlesyndication.com http: https: ; frame-src 'self' googleads.g.doubleclick.net *.googlesyndication.com; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  *.googletagmanager.com [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) [www.gstatic.com](http://www.gstatic.com) [www.clarity.ms](http://www.clarity.ms) *.googlesyndication.com google.com *.google-analytics.com *.facebook.net; script-src-attr 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; report-uri /log.php"

Comment: Can you share a [mre]?

Comment: Sure, an example of the log?

Comment: Please read the linked guidance - what would be more helpful is a stripped down example of the code you're using that can be leveraged to reproduce the issue locally (alongside all pertinent debugging information, including any error logs).

Comment: I am actually not getting img-src violations anymore. I am getting style-src-elem violations, which I am getting when running it on Firefox as well. "blocked-uri": "inline","status-code": 0. This is the violation in the log. This is the style-src-elem policy I have: "style-src-elem 'self' fonts.googleapis.com *.facebook.net www.gstatic.com". Do you need more information or is this sufficient for now?

Comment: Unfortunately what you’ve provided still doesn’t meet our [mre] guidance, because there isn’t enough detail for potential answerers to reliably reproduce the issue you’re describing. Please also include pertinent error messages and other debugging details in the body of your question - they’re not really readable in comments.

Comment: I just updated the body of the question adding more details. Hope this helps.